# How do you inject in dotnet core project in static method an IConfiguration object?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, stackexchange.redis

I have a Redis store similar to [this one](https://github.com/taswar/RedisForNetDevelopers/blob/master/4.RedisHashes/RedisHash/RedisHash/RedisStore.cs). My problem is, since I am using .Net Core, on line 15, I should use configuration object that I normally inject in the constructor.

However, one cannot inject the configuration object in the static constructor, as static constructor should be parameterless in C#.

I tried adding a static method to initialise the config object, but then the constructor throws `NullReferenceException` because obviously the ctor is still called first, before the Init method, and it needs the config object... so what to do?

Doesn't seem like a good workaround.

Comment: Camilo, yes I am using DI in the project.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure why those statics were added in the example I found (the github link), and that's why I was trying to make that work first. What is your idea, why is it better with interfaces and why would the author use static singleton - for comparison? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing all that work with statics and trying to get it to work (hint: it'd never work with a static constructor), I'd suggest you to move to newer patterns and use DI correctly.

If you don't really need the lazyness, this is as simple as injecting `IConnectionMultiplexer`:

```
services.AddScoped<IConnectionMultiplexer>(s => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration["someSettings"]));
```

If you do need the lazyness:

```
// public interface IRedisStore { IConnectionMultiplexer RedisConnection { get; } } 
public class RedisStore : IRedisStore
{
    private readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection;

    public RedisStore(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            EndPoints = { configuration["someSettings"] }
        };

        LazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions));
    }

    public IConnectionMultiplexer RedisConnection => LazyConnection.Value;        
}
```

and you'd inject it with:

```
services.AddScoped<IRedisStore, RedisStore>());
```